# WP7 - web service calls return null instead of collections

Tags: windows-phone-7, webservice-client

I want to consume a webservice and particulary a method which return a collection. When i consume it by using a console application, it works. But when I try to consume it with a WP7 App, i only get a null object or empty list.

I have try to get a simple string and it works with both apps (console and WP7) so I think that I only get this issue with collections.

With Fiddler i monitor the traffic and i can see that the webservice return the right collections, with many items, but the return is still empty in my WP7 App.

Other details :

- I'm not the owner of the webservice
- I'm using the WP7emulator
- I meet the same issue but his solution doesn't help me:   ([WP7 consume a WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678619/wp7-consume-a-wcf-service))

Here is a code sample :

```
private void LoadData()
{
    client = new Service.WsivPortTypeClient();

    client.getLinesCompleted += new EventHandler<Service.getLinesCompletedEventArgs>(client_getLinesCompleted);
    client.getLinesAsync(null);
}

static void client_getLinesCompleted(object sender, Service.getLinesCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //e.Results is always null or empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And what do you have in e.Error ?
Check if it's not null, you might get useful informations. Regards

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply.
e.Error is null and not exceptions are raised during execution.